# Passing Variables between Objective C Categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I'm using Objective C categories.  There are 3 files

```
MainClass.h
MainClass+Category1.h
MainClass+Category2.h
```

I'm trying to either pass variables between MainClass.h and MainClass+Category1.h or between MainClass+Category1.h and MainClass+Category2.h

The transaction requires them to all work together.  Is my only option NSNotificationCenter ?  Can I use delegates.  I was getting errors when trying to use delegates.  The methods were not being recognized.

Comment: Did you import the appropriate categories where you were trying to use them?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details about what you are doing. On the surface it makes no sense. Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to either pass variables between MainClass.h and MainClass+Category1.h or between MainClass+Category1.h and MainClass+Category2.h

That doesn't make a lot of sense, really. Categories simply add methods to an existing class. If you have access to the source code for the class, you can add any necessary instance variables or properties there and use them from the files that define the categories.